# JSCL - why this mysterious error?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, jscl

http://learnlispthehardway.org/try-lisp/

```
CL-USER> (defun saynextof ( a b c )(write a)) 
SAYNEXTOF
CL-USER> (saynextof "fred" "jim" "shiela")
ERROR[!]: too few arguments
```

(For the benefit of this form validation: This does completely describe the problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSCL requires (differently from the [standard](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_wr_pr.htm#write)) more than one parameter in the `write` function, so this is the reason of the error.

If you use `print` instead, the error does not appear.

Comment: Thanks. "if you use print instead, the error does not appear." Unfortunately quotes do! :-)

Comment: Thanks. ` (format t "A~%"a )` doesn't work (prints A) but `(format t "~A" a)` does.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the error is thrown by the `write` function:

```
CL-USER> (write "foo")
ERROR[!]: too few arguments
CL-USER>
```

I just downloaded the latest version of JSCL from [GitHub](https://github.com/davazp/jscl) and compiled it. With that version, the error does not occur. The commit messages for JSCL's `print.lisp` suggest that there used to be a problem in the implementation of `write` which could cause "too few arguments" errors:

```
Author: David Vazquez <davazp@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jan 4 19:23:28 2016 +0100

    Fix the write function

    It was using write-aux with too few arguments.
```